# What can cause working OpenGL render code to render black textures if used after some other rendering code?

Tags: opengl

I'm implementing a HUD for FreeCAD (i.e. some graphics on top of the CAD view).

My code works nicely but if there is any content in display other than my HUD i.e. the CAD document contains some objects, then all my HUD elements that are rendered with textures appear black. If for debugging purposes I render them with color then the color works so I suspect this related to the textures.

Below is the code that does the rendering (this is the fixed pippelin OpenGL 1.1).

So what can cause this code to render the textures as black when run after some other rendering code but let it work correctly when there is no other (or very little) other rendering going on before this?

And how should I debug this?

The FreeCAD code base is huge and it uses the Coin3D library which is also huge so looking into that seems daunting to trace what is causing this.

Probably my fault but I can't spot it.

```
glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
GLfloat depthrange[2];
glGetFloatv(GL_DEPTH_RANGE, depthrange);
GLdouble projectionmatrix[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionmatrix);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();


const float NEARVAL = 0.1f;
const float FARVAL = 10.0f;
const float dim = NEARVAL * float(tan(M_PI / 8.0)); 
glFrustum(-dim, dim, -dim, dim, NEARVAL, FARVAL);

SbMatrix mx;
SoCamera* cam = this->getSoRenderManager()->getCamera();

mx = cam->orientation.getValue();

mx = mx.inverse();
mx[3][2] = -7.0; // Translate away from the projection point (along z axis).

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadMatrixf((float*)mx);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0,(void*) g_VertexArray.data() );
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, g_TextureCoordArray.data() );
glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);
glIndexPointer( 2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(void*) g_IndexArray.data() );
int b=0;
int tc = (int) g_TriangleFans.size();
for (int i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_Textures[g_TriangleTextures[i]]);
    int n = g_TriangleFans[i];
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, b, n);
    b += n;
    }

glPopMatrix();

glDepthRange(depthrange[0], depthrange[1]);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixd(projectionmatrix);

glPopAttrib();
```

Comment: I just love "drive by shooters" who vote down without a word ... such a delightful and constructive bunch of people.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was, I had some code that was used to initialise some static data structures and I did the texture generation there in the first OpenGL context, thus the textures I generated were not valid for any subsequent contexts.